# Viewing table of contents in Word while editing

Tags: microsoft-word, split-window

I am editing a long Word document and would like to keep the table of contents in view so that I can stay oriented as I work on the main part of the document.
Is there a way to do this, perhaps with a vertical split view with the table of contents on the left and the main text on right?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the [document map](http://www.addintools.com/documents/office/where-document-map.html).

#### What it looks like

It will display the table of content on the left of your document:

[image]

#### How to display in Word 2003

To display the document map in Word 2003:

- Go to Menu
- View
- Click on "Document Map" or "Navigation pane"

#### How to display in Word 2007+

In word 2007 or higher:

- In the ribbon
- View tab
- Show/Hide section
- Click on the checkbox "Navigation pane"
- Click on Document Map

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I found it in a slightly different place in Word 2007: View Tab on Ribbon, Show/Hide section, check 'Document Map'. But exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @KE.: thanks for pointing out the right wording (my Word app is not in english :)). I've edited my answer thanks to your comment.

Comment: just to whom it may concern in my word the "Document map" is called "Navigation pan"..

Comment: @Aiya: thanks. I've edited my answer to reflect your comment

Comment: It is "Navigation pane", at least in Word 2010.